# MySQL High Write Latency

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I'm developing a social-like application which is currently deployed using AWS services. In particular, the DB runs on RDS using MYSQL. 
So far, we're testing the app using a limited number of users (mostly friends) resulting in an average of 15 Write IOPS/sec.

The real problem is related to the very high writing latency of the db, which is always above 100ms. The RDS instance is a db.m3.xlarge which is much more than what we need.

I tried to perform a load test in a separate instance (identical configuration of DB and EC2) but i've not been able to reproduce such a high latency, even if I was sending a much higher number of requests. So I thought it may be due to table fragmentation, but i've not yet run a table optimisation, because the db wouldn't be accessible during this procedure.

Do you have any experience with this problem?

**MORE INFO**

- We're using mysql version 5.6.21 with INNODB as storage engine.
- The whole DB is about 100MB in size
- The biggest table (called `Message`) has about 790k rows. Concerning this table, the following query

  ```
  insert into Message (user_id, creationDate, talk_id, text, id) 
  values (2015, '2015-02-01 16:40:06.737', 18312, 'Some text ', 904870)
  ```

  took 11s to be executed.
- Even worse, the query

  ```
  insert into Comment (anonymous, user_id, creationDate, deleted, post_id, text, id) 
  values (1, 107347, '2015-02-01 16:40:01.849', 0, 124888, 'Comment text', 265742)
  ```

  took 14s, but the table Comment has about 160k.

Those two tables are generated by:

```
CREATE TABLE `comment` (
    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `anonymous` bit(1) NOT NULL,
    `creationDate` datetime NOT NULL,
    `deleted` bit(1) NOT NULL,
    `text` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `post_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `FK_jhvt6d9ap8gxv67ftrmshdfhj` (`user_id`),
    KEY `FK_apirq8ka64iidc18f3k6x5tc5` (`post_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_apirq8ka64iidc18f3k6x5tc5` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `post` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_jhvt6d9ap8gxv67ftrmshdfhj` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `kuser` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `message` (
    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `creationDate` datetime NOT NULL,
    `text` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `talk_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `FK_d0j091jvk2y4mmfbadnqlohtf` (`user_id`),
    KEY `FK_64tr15t6wu5y9u143gxt6o3g2` (`thread_id `),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_64tr15t6wu5y9u143gxt6o3g2` FOREIGN KEY (`thread_id`) REFERENCES `thread` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_d0j091jvk2y4mmfbadnqlohtf` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `kuser` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**SOME PLOTS**

Using [AppDynamics](http://www.appdynamics.com) I've been able to extract the following plots:

- *Wait States*: Isn't the query end time too big?

  [image: SQL Wait states]
- *Page Buffer*:

  [image: Page Buffer]
- *Write Latency and Queue*:

  [image: RDS Stats]

**Query Cache**

```
+------------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name                | Value     |
+------------------------------+-----------+
| query_cache_limit            | 1048576   |
| query_cache_min_res_unit     | 4096      |
| query_cache_size             | 1048576   |
| query_cache_type             | OFF       |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF       |
+------------------------------+-----------+
```

Thank for your help!

Andrea

Comment: We're gonna need way more details. You haven't stated MySQL version, storage engine, database scheme, data size, sample queries, etc. We have very high write system with no issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marcus. I've added more info.

Comment: I expected to see `id` as UNSIGNED and AUTO_INCREMENT. How are you generating the IDs?

Comment: We're using Hibernate (JPA) to query the DB. Hibernate keeps the last used id for each table and uses it to insert new rows

Comment: MySQL allocates space 4 extents (1mb each) at a time. [Profile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html) your queries to ensure it's MySQL time, not something else. Yes, it can become fragmented, though fragmentation only really affects reading large numbers of sequential records, not searching and selecting individual records, which is most common.

Comment: Thanks! I'm waiting for the db to be loaded with requests to profile the insert queries. If it can help, I got those timings (14s and 11s) from the `slow_log` table in the `mysql` schema.

Comment: The slow log usually includes more information than just the time.

Comment: I've update the question with some stats. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I got in touch with RDS engineers from amazon and they gave me the solution.
Such a high latency was due to a very low performing storage type. Indeed, I was using the default 5GB SSD (which they call GP2) which gives 3 IOPS per GB of storage, resulting in 15 IOPS when my application required about 50 IOPS or even more.

Therefore, they suggested me to change the storage type to `Magnetic` which provides 100 IOPS as baseline. Moreover, I've also been able to decrease the instance type because the bottleneck was only the disk.

The migration took about 3h due to the very low performance of the source disk (GP2).

Hope it may help someone out there!

Comment: Didn't know about the 3 IOPS per GB of storage rule. Googling how to find out if I'm over the limit or not, AWS support had this to say: 'Currently there is no metric available to view the GP2 IO Credit usage and balance. An approachable method is to monitor the metrics like DiskQueueDepth, ReadLatency and WriteLatency. These metrics will go up if your RDS instance ran out of IO credits. So, if you see a sudden increase in these metrics and stay consistenly high, it indicates that you ran out of IO credits.' Source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=182707

Answer (score 0):

Your query profile shows that the "Query end" time is very large. This may be caused by a very (too) large [query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_size). Every time you perform an update statement (INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE), the query cache must be updated (every query that reads from the updated tables is invalidated).

Comment: Thanks once again! I checked the variables associated to the query cache (see question) and it looks like the cache is disabled